# Rhymbox can't play mp3 files, but videos can

Tags: rhythmbox

I have installed gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly. I removed Rhythmbox and then reinstalled it, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Had the same issue**

*steps to resolve issue* ;

1- open terminal

2- type the following 2 commands ;

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

*Followed by*

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gxine libdvdread4 icedax tagtool libdvd-pkg  easytag id3tool lame libxine2-ffmpeg nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321 libavcodec-extra gstreamer1.0-libav
```

*remembering to type -- y -- to each command.*

This should resolve your issue with Rythembox and allow you to play mp3 files etc.